# How to check if an extension is enabled in CKAN templates

Tags: ckan

Is there a way that we can check whether an extension is enabled/installed in a CKAN template?

I am looking for something like:

```
{% if ?????? %}
    Some logic
{% endif %}
```

What shall the `???` be?

The `???` can be a helper function (e.g. h.get("A FUNCTION NAME") ), but I wondering if there is a way to check the existence of an extension directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of currently enabled plugins might be tucked away in the template's environment somewhere, but it will vary between Flask and Pylons templates and perhaps best not relied upon.

I've seen it done a few times as helpers, as you mention. Alternatively you could add the list of enabled plugins to `g` (globals).

It seems a reasonably common thing to want to use in a template, so once you've added it to your CKAN extension, why not contribute it to CKAN core too? You'd create an issue on ckan and see if the tech team agrees, before creating a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked the core code and found the list of enabled plugins has already been added to `g` (globals). Here is the source code [https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/lib/app_globals.py#L58]
```
{% if <RPLUGINNAME> in g.plugins %}
    Some logic
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Perfect! :) :) :)